# how to convert c/c++ loop containing two initial variables to matlab loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

i need to convert a C for loop with 2 variables ( see 2nd loop in provided code ) to MATLAB..

```
 for(i=2; i<=count; i++)
 for(j=i-1, n=1; n<=count+1-i; j+=2, n++)
 {
  table[j][i]=table[j+1][i-1] - table[j-1][i-1];
 }
```

Comment: also note that , there is no condition related to variable "j" for breaking loop

Comment: Make a for loop over variable n, and simply increment j inside your loop.